# css3 media query not working -- background color change on resize

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get my media queries to actually display.. I'm trying to eventually get it so that my text will re-size based on browser size, but I'm just trying to do a test run to see if it will even work.

I'm trying to have it so that when the browser resizes to 1200px in width the page background turns red. Here's my css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
   .main {
     background-color: red;
         }
    }
```

and here is my stylesheet link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 1200px)" href="tek_bigscreen.css">
```

I also have another stylesheet with no media queries in it linking to the page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="tekstyle.css">
```

Any idea why the media query won't work? Also any insight as to how to properly resize the text would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why your background is not turning red.  But the best way I've found to properly resize your text is to use ems.

Something like:

```
body {
    font-size:100%;
}
h1 {
    font-size:2em;
}

@media only screen and (min-width:500px) and (max-width:1200px) {
    body {
        font-size:15px
    }
}
```

`font-size:100%` will make 1em equal to the browser's default font size, usually 16px, and when you reduce the font size on the body tag, everything that is set in ems inside the body will be proportionally reduced in size.

**Edit:** Also, and this is just a suggestion because it's the way I do it, but instead of putting the media queries in the link tags.  Just keep all of your media queries inside the CSS file and use this [poly-fill](https://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) to make them work with old IE.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I made my body font-size 100% and made the font on the page in em, but resizing the browser window is not changing the font size :(

Comment: ahhh it just worked! I just had to add in another div class I was wrapping around my stuff. Thank you so much! :)

Comment: O good, I was making a jsFiddle for you after I saw your comment.  If you're interested here it is.  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X3n3p/3/)

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to include the media attribute in the style sheet link if you have `@media` in the style sheet itself. Indeed, it may be causing an error—I'm not sure. Perhaps try putting your code into the regular style sheet and see what happens, or just put the color declaration in the first style sheet without the `@media` wrapper.

Comment: I tried putting the code below in my regular style sheet but it's still not working :(

Comment: Without seeing your HTML, we can only guess at what is going on. It might be worth trying `background: red` instead of `background-color`. But a test case can easily show that your code should work. `<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  
 <style media="all">
 .main {width: 500px; height: 500px; background: blue;}
 @media screen and (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
     .main {
          background: red;
     }
 }
 </style>
  
 </head>
 <body>
 
     <div class="main">
 
 </div>
 
 </body>
 </html>
`